# Why does include with brackets not find the header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a header file `DCM_Types.hh` which is in fact located in the project directory. Why cannot find the source file?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text; screenshots are not particularly useful.

Comment: first, post as text, then a screenshot _without_ the file extensions is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angle brackets are used to indicate the inclusion of system headers. Use quotation marks to include a non-system header.

`#include <system_header.h>`

`#include "personal_header.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Try #include "DCM_Types.hh"
<> if for system headers
"" is your headers in your program/searches in the current directory